# Merging a pandas crosstab to a data table and getting partial results

Tags: python, pandas

I have in the past merged crosstab results to my data without issue, but today it is nothing but errors and frustration.

I have a list like:

```
TID PL Amount Category
--- -- ------ --------
1   A      10 Hardware
1   B      15 Software
2   C      50 Service
```

I use `ct = pd.crosstab(data['TID'], columns=data['Category'], values=data['Amount'], aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)` and get

```
Category  Hardware  Software  Support
TID
--------  --------  --------  -------
1             10.0      15.0      0.0
2              0.0       0.0     50.0
```

I then merge my accounts:

```
TID  Name
---  ----
  1  This
  2  That
```

with `pd.merge(accounts, ct, on="TID", how="left")` and get the expected result:

```
TID  Name  Hardware  Software  Support
---  ----  --------  --------  -------
  1  This      10.0      15.0      0.0
  2  That       0.0       0.0     50.0
```

This works in a Jupyter notebook without issue.

Sadly, in the real file (full of proprietary data) the `fillna(0)` on the crosstab doesn't replace the NaNs, so I have to manually run `fillna` in the Hardware, Software, and Support columns. Then when I try to get a total column `data['Total'] = data['Hardware'] + data['Software'] + data['Services']` I get a `length of values does not match length of index` error.

If I use the `margins` and `margins_name` parameters of the `crosstab` I get an error during the merge:

```
You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

I can't figure out how to cast the index of the crosstab as an int64.

I can't figure out how to flatten the crosstab into a regular dataframe with columns `'TID', 'Name', 'Hardware', 'Software', 'Service', 'Total'`.  `reset_index` looks right but then I still can't cast that column as an int64 and pull off the merge.

Any suggestions? It's frustrating that I cannot replicate this error outside of my code.

Comment: Update: I did get ```reset_index``` to flatten the crosstab and added the margin and margin name "All", but I still can't merge because the TID column of the crosstab is an object. I tried ```ct.astype({'TID': 'int64'})``` but I get an error about ```invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'All'```.

Answer (score 1):

I see [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) that crosstab by default drops NaN values `dropna=True`.

Seems like you may not be able to `fillna()` NaN values that never got populated, and also lead to the lengths not matching. I'd try:

`ct = pd.crosstab(data['TID'], columns=data['Category'], values=data['Amount'], aggfunc='sum', dropna=False).fillna(0)`